# Google Maps API equivalent of GEPlugin.createFolder()

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The Google Earth API allows you to add Features to Folders (KmlFolder), making it easy to show/hide multiple Features by calling setVisibility() on the parent Folder. Folders can also be arranged in a hierarchy, meaning that a call to setVisibility() on a parent Folder would also affect all child Folders.

This would be very useful for the Google Maps app I'm writing, but I can't find an equivalent in the Google Maps v3 API :-( Have I missed something or will I need to code my own?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps does [support](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport#googlemaps) KML folder feature. However the visibility feature [partially](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps) support, but for your use it works (yes on  - child placemarks inherit their visibility)